# Short way of overloading function?

Tags: c#, overloading

is there any why to do this in a shorter way?
I thought about something like `void DoSth(int i) : DoSth(i, this);`.

```
class Foo
{

   void DoSth(int i)
   {
      DoSth(i, this);
   }

   static void DoSth(int i, Foo foo)
   {
      // do sth
   }

}
```

Edit: forgot `static` at second function

Comment: Nope, I guess that is the shortest one. Because if you use one function only, then it won't be an overloading.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the second DoSth is static.

Comment: There is no overloading in your sample... So some clarification/sample update may be needed to see which answer actually answers the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using C# 6 then you can use expression bodies on method-like members:

```
class Foo
{
    public DoSth(int i) => DoSth(i, this); 

    static void DoSth(int i, Foo foo)
    {
          // do sth
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually `DoSth(int i){DoSth(i,this);} ` is the same number of characters as `DoSth(int i)=>DoSth(i,this);`

Comment: But it looks cleaner :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use optional parameters:

```
class Foo
{    
   void DoSth(int i, Foo foo = null)
   {
      // do sth.. use "this" if "foo" is null
   }

}
```